# how to display parameter hint in vscode when work on c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm new to C# and even after I've done some research on how to display parameter hints in VScode while using C#, I'm not able to solve this issue.

I'm using mac and I opened preferences > settings > Extensions > C# configuration, but after that which value should I change to display the parameter hints?

I was able to see the parameter hints before, but it doesn't appear and not really sure why this happened..

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this before your method or variable.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the sprite towards the position pos
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="posZ">the position to move towards</param>
    /// <param name="speed">the speed to move at </param>
    /// <param name="setDisplayAngle"> true if you want to orient the sprites display</param>
    /// <returns> true if we got there </returns>
```

Just change the text in the comment field to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl + Shift + p
2. Write "OmniSharp: Select Project" and press Enter.
3. Choose the solution workspace entry.

and it worked now.